# How to change the image using select box in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi Friends here i have change the value of the text by selecting the different value but i want an images also to change accordingly.

here fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/TU6tp/44/

Shall we include image also like text and while change the image also change?

**Code**

```
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select 
   ng-model="selectedItem" 
   ng-options="S.label for S in selectables">
  </select>
 <p>Selected item value: {{selectedItem.value}}</p>
 <p>Selected item image: {{selectedItem.img}}</p>
</div>
```

and i saw one more link http://jsfiddle.net/wktwL/ also i am confused how to change image on selecting. please some one help me out in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this http://jsfiddle.net/TU6tp/45/,
just put the value of your image  into the src of `img` element

```
<img src='{{selectedItem}}'/>



$scope.selectables = [
        { label: 'A', value: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg'},
        { label:'B', value:'http://hdwallpaper.freehdw.com/0001/nature-landscapes_widewallpaper_nature-s-beauty_9645.jpg'}
    ];
```

And your value for the selectable array should contain the path to the image

Comment: thanks @Naeem Shaikh i got it but, my images in local "image" folder if i set path for that images is not coming, any other thing we have to do??

Comment: I didnt know that wouldnt work for `relative paths`, but if you need to add the full path, you can prefix your images path value with `window.location.hostname`, you will then get the path :)

Comment: @Naeem Shaikh Hi, I had same problem and thanks to your solution I got it worked. But I got only left `selected` option part. How can i do that could you update your jsfiddle.